# Xamarin Forms and Visual Studio for Mac - Errors while compiling

Tags: ios, visual-studio, xamarin.forms

I've installed the latest version of Visual Studio for Mac and when I'm trying to compile and launch in debug mode (on the iOS simulator) an Hello World app it throws a lot of error while compiling.
In the screenshot you can see what happend and what type of errors are... 
I tried everything: re-install Visual Studio for Mac, update NuGet packages and dependencies, update Xamarin Forms files... but still doesn't work...

[image: Visual Studio for Mac errors while compiling and debugging iOS app]

Comment: You have an error in your LanchScreen.Storyboard. Try reseting that file to the original

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Solved with these steps:

1. Closed Visual Studio Mac
2. Opened Xcode
3. Xcode asked to update additional components
4. Closed Xcode after the update finished
5. Opend VS again, cleaned the solution and compiled my project successfully